# While Mail Forwarding with exim, how do I rewrite the To header with true destination address

Tags: exim

I have mail forwarding setup with exim using a domain forwarding file.

```
virtual_aliases_nostar:
  driver = redirect
  allow_defer
  allow_fail
  data = ${if exists{/etc/valiases/$domain}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/valiases/$domain}}}}
  file_transport = address_file
  group = mail
  pipe_transport = virtual_address_pipe
  retry_use_local_part
  domains = lsearch;/etc/localdomains
  unseen
```

It is working fine.

However, I would like to rewrite the "to" header.  In my system filter, I would like to put something like:

```
  headers remove to
  headers add "To: $recipient:"
```

I've tried:

```
  headers remove to
  headers add "To: $recipient:"

  headers remove to
  headers add "To: $h_env-to:"

  headers remove to
  headers add "To: $env-to:"
```

The intent is to have the end recipient see their own email address in the To: line of their mail client.

I can't seem to figure out what the correct header is for the final destination of the email so that I can put it in the to header.  I've read through the Exim docs and can't seem to find it.  I've also looked in the headers in an email at a mail client and can't see it there either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the existing `To:` header (which may contain other recipients or the name of a mailing list) with the computed final destination of the email? You already have some code to figure out where the email has to end up, so use that:

```
headers remove to
headers add "To: ${if exists{/etc/valiases/$domain}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/valiases/$domain}}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
headers remove to
headers add "To: $original_local_part@original_domain"
```